# Cannot start a session from external location

Tags: php, session

I have always been able to connect to (and start sessions on) our database internally, here on our network.

We recently opened up external access, but then the problems started.  I can access any html file as well as phpinfo.php but no other php pages because they try to start a session.

Every page includes a require_once to config.php which starts a session and checks their level of access - if level == 0 they are redirected to the login page.

```
session_start();
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); //300 seconds = 5 minutes   
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/include/db_pdo.php");
function includeHeader($title) {        
    require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/include/head_pdo.php");        
}
$level = 0; 
if (isset($_SESSION['level'])){
    $level = $_SESSION['level'];
}
if ($level == 0) {
    header('Location: /login/login.php' ) ;
}
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't get past session_start().   I have cleared the cookies on my browser, and I can see a cookie created when I access config.php (start a session) but then it goes nowhere.

As stated before, internal access works beautifully.  Any suggestions gratefully received.

Webserver is running on a Synology Diskstation DS216++ (fully patched), running apache 2.4 and php 7.0

Comment: _"Unfortunately, it doesn't get past session_start()"_ - and how exactly have you verified that? What happens instead? Errors? Have you configured PHP properly to show all errors? Have you checked the log files (if configured)?

Comment: I added echos to config.php echo "This is line before session start"; echo "This is line after session start";  It doesn't display the second echo. Come Monday I will  turn errors on.

Comment: Where? And don't say you put one _before_ session_start ...

Comment: Because I cannot connect to the server from home I created 3 config.php files with an echo at different stages in the script.  The first script had the echo BEFORE the session start to make sure the page was being called.  The second script had the echo after the session start was called. And the third script had the echo at the end of the script to see if it completed the script.  That way I could check each of the scripts that night when I got home.